# Android change widget color at runtime UPDATED

Tags: android

I have a widget, with a framelayout.

Is there a way to change my widgets color/shape in runtime?

I am using a shape xml for the background.

**update:**

i tried:
1,

```
            Paint paint=new Paint(); 

            Bitmap bitmap=Bitmap.createBitmap(100, 100, Config.ARGB_8888);
            Canvas canvas=new Canvas(bitmap);
            paint.setColor(Color.RED);
            canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(1,1,111,111), 10, 10, paint);

            updateViews.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.FL, bitmap);
```

--> error loading widget

2,

```
updateViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.FL, R.drawable.blue);
```

--> error loading widget

Comment: After which events do you want to change the color/shape? Things like onFocus or onClick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try making a workaround by adding an `ImageView` to fill the whole `FrameLayout` and then using the `RemoteViews.setImageViewResource(int viewId, int srcId)`.

Comment: i tried it before, but I get an "error loading widget" on this :(

Comment: That is weird, are you sure that `RL` is an `ImageView`? I have used setImageViewResource before and it worked.

Comment: Yes, you should use `setImageViewResource` only on an imageView or an imageButton, hence the suggestion to make it fill your whole RelativeLayout or FrameLayout.

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume your widget is a TextView, and you want to change its color to white.

First you grab a reference to it, by using the ID that you specified in the XML layout:

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewId);
```

Now, you can just set the color:

```
textView.setBackgroundColorResource(R.color.white);
```

Comment: thats not working in widget mode, only on activity, on widget we can use only updateViews

Comment: ouch, sorry, I read "widget" as in "GUI component", not as in "Android widget, those in the home screen".

Answer (score 0):

For Color:

```
view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
```

For shape or any resourse:

```
view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.my_shape);
```

Comment: thats not working in widget mode, only on activity, on widget we can use only updateViews

Comment: my bad. I thought you meant the widget package **android.widget**